# How to rollback a transaction in subclass when an exception is thrown in super class

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, exception, transactions

Consider the following scenario in Spring MVC 4: There is subclass `RoleDao` which inherits `GenericDao`. A method `createRole()` in `RoleDao` calls two methods `method1`,`method2` in `GenericDao` using Programmatic Tranasction Management. Both `method1` and `method2` catches exceptions on their own right.See code below. My question is how to rollback a transaction in method `createRole` whenever an exception is thrown in either `method1` or `method2` of the super class `GenericDao`

```
public class RoleDao extends GenericDao {

public int createRole() {
try
    {
       TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
      TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
    this.methhod1();
    this.methhod2();
    transactionManager.commit(status);

    }
    catch (InvalidResultSetAccessException e) 
    {
    transactionManager.rollback(status);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
    catch (DataAccessException e)
    {
    transactionManager.rollback(status);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
public class GenericDao{

public int method1() {
try
    {
       ..........
    .........
    }
    catch (InvalidResultSetAccessException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
    catch (DataAccessException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
public int method2() {
try
    {
       .........
    .........
    }
    catch (InvalidResultSetAccessException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
    catch (DataAccessException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When you say _rollback back_, you probably mean roll forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all exceptions in the superclass methods, they should be handled by the subclass methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try using spring annotations . @Transactional over RoleDao class might help you here .

Comment: I can not combine Declarative and Programmatic Transaction Management.As regards to Programmatic , I quote " provides extreme flexibility, but it is difficult to maintain"